# Visa Type for Nesin Mathematics Village, Turkey

Tags: visas, tourist-visas, turkey, study, summer

I am a student travelling from India, and I am unsure of the type of visa to apply for when travelling for the purpose of attending the [Nesin Mathematics Village](http://www.nesinkoyleri.org/eng/events-detail.php?egitimkod=332). It's a summer school type programme that hands out *no qualifications or degrees or diplomas*; it's just a place of learning.

This makes the visa application difficult for me. Should I apply for a tourist visa or a student visa? If you have attended the same, which visa did you apply for?

Comment: I don't know about Turkey, but in most countries student visas are for those in programs that grant degrees or diplomas, and those attending summer programs like this need tourist visas.

Comment: Have you asked the organisers? They have certainly had students who need visas before, and might be able to help you make the application.

Comment: @phoog That's what I think as well. But I really don't want to take any chances.

Comment: @MJeffryes I did contact them nearly a week back. They haven't responded yet. I get the feeling they don't understand my question...